# Integral w.r.t counting measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Definition of integral is given 
$$
\int f d\mu=\sup{\left\{\int s\ d\mu : 0 \leq s \leq f , s \ \text{ is a simple function} \right\}}
$$

Now let $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a non-negative measurable function on the natural numbers and $\mu$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Prove the following using definition of integral:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}}f\ d\mu =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)
$$

I could prove that $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f\ d\mu \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)$ using simple functions of the form $f_N=\sum_{k=1}^N f(k)1\{n=k\}$. How do I prove the other direction ?

Note: We shouldn't use Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: You can prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)$ is greater than or equal to anything in the set that you are taking the $\sup$.

Comment: @VuAnHoa: That's what I had trouble proving. Like taking simple functions and all. Can you give a rough outline of the procedure involved?

Comment: Take any simple function $0 \leq s \leq f$ and let $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ be its positive values. If $s^{-1}(y_i)$ is infinite for some $i$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{f(k)} = \infty$ because $f$ must take values $\leq y_i > 0$ infinitely often. Else $\int s d\mu = \sum y_i \mu(s^{-1}(y_i)) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} s(k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{f(k)}$.

Comment: @VuAnHoa: Thanks, the argument is simple and clear :)

Comment: Here is a link to another posts about this - although the accepted answer there uses monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) are just finite linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets. In this context our measure space is discrete and all sets are measurable, so a simple function is just a linear combination of (characteristic functions of) points. More precisely, in our context every simple function takes the form
$$s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^m s_k \mathbf{1}_{\{a_k\}}(n),$$
for some $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $(a_k)_{k=1}^m\subset \mathbb{N}$ pairwise different numbers. Note how $m=\infty$ is also allowed, because also infinite sets of natural numbers are measurable.

Say that $s$ is one of the objects that the supremum is taken over, so a simple function with $0\le s(n)\le f(n)$ for all $n$. In particular $s_k=s(a_k)\le f(a_k)$.

Then

$$\int_{\mathbb{N}} s\,d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^m s_k\le \sum_{k=1}^m f(a_k)\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k).$$

In the last step we used that $f$ is non-negative. By definition of the supremum as the *least* upper bound this implies

$$\int_{\mathbb{N}} f\,d\mu \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k).$$

Comment: $m=\infty $ is not allowed because then it won't be finite linear combination of indicator functions.

Comment: That is not correct. Read again.