# How to integrate this nonnegative function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Consider the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $P(\mathbb{N})$ and the count measure $\mu$. If $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$, then
> $$\int fd\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n).$$

I feel that I need to prove at first that $f$ is a measurable function and then define a sequence ${f_n}\in L^+$ s. t. $f=\sum_{n}f_n$, but I have no idea if it's the right way nor how to do it. I need help.

Also, before I post this question, I've found a similar question on this link
[Integral w.r.t counting measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451033/integral-w-r-t-counting-measure), yet I'm having a hard time to get this one.

Note: I can use any theorem, no restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since the $\sigma$-algebra in the domain is $P(\mathbb{N})$, all functions  $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \Bbb R$ are measurable.
2. Given  $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$. For each $k\in \Bbb N$, let $E_k= \Bbb N \cap [0,k]$ and $f_k= f\cdot \chi_{E_k}$. Then, $f_k$ are simple functions, $f_k \nearrow f$ and $\int f_k d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{k} f(n)$. So, we have,
   $$\int fd\mu = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int f_k d\mu = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{k} f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n).$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't see how ${f_k }$ is increasing to $f$. Could you give me more details? I can understand the following results,  but not that step...

Comment: @JakePark , Suppose $j, k \in \Bbb N$, $0 \leq j <k$ then for $p \in \Bbb N$, we have: 

 1. if $p\leq j$ then $f_j(p)=f(p)=f_k(p)$;
 2. if $j <p\leq k$ then $f_j(p)=0 \leq f(p)=f_k(p)$;
 3. if $k < p$ then $f_j(p)=0=f_k(p)$;

So, if $ j <k$, then, for all $p \in \Bbb N$, $f_j(p) \leq f_k(p)$. 

Now, given any $p \in \Bbb N$, for all $k>p$, $f_k(p)=f(p)$. So we have $f_k \nearrow f$.